# PHP, Fatal error: Call to undefined method. But method is defined?

Tags: php

So in this code all I am trying to do is create a view chores page.
I have created a chore class and a choreDAO class, which my view_chores page is calling from.

I have used the exact same code with other pages such as view_members and they also have the other two classe and they work fine!

The error occurs in the view_chores.php file below; this line of code:

```
echo "<b>Title:</b> " . $chore->getChoreName() . "<br />";
```

any help would be great. thank you!

Here is my view_chores.php page.

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once 'includes/Member.php';
require_once 'includes/MemberDAO.php';
require_once 'includes/Chore.php';
require_once 'includes/ChoreDAO.php';
require_once 'includes/session.php';
confirm_logged_in(); // needs to come before any html because it does a redirect
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require 'toolbar.php';
        $member = ($_SESSION['member']);

        $choreDAO = new ChoreDAO();
        $chores = $choreDAO->getChores();


        echo "<p>Hello " . $member->getFN() . "</p>";
        echo "<p>These are the current chores:  </p>";


        foreach ($chores as $chore) {
           echo "<b>Title:</b> " . $chore->getChoreName() . "<br />";
           echo "</p>";


        }


        echo $display; ?>
        <a href="add_chore_form.php">Add Chore?</a>



    </body>
</html>

<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

Here is my Chore.php

```
    <?php
class Chore {
private $id;
private $chore_name;



public function __construct($i, $chore_name) {
    $this->id = $i;
    $this->chore_name = $chore_name;


}
public function getId() { return $this->id; }
public function getChoreName() { return $this->chore_name; }



public function setId($i) { $this->id = $i; }
public function setChoreName($cn) { $this->ChoreName = $cn; }


}
?>
```

and here is my ChoreDAO.php

```
    <?php
     require_once 'DAO.php';

     class ChoreDAO extends DAO {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function insert($chore) {
        if (!isset($chore)) {
            throw new Exception("Chore required");
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Chore(chore_name) VALUES (?)";
        $params = array($chore->getChoreName());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not save Chore: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute();
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve new chore's id: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $id = $row[0];
        $chore->setId($id);
    }

    public function delete($chore) {
        if (!isset($chore)) {
            throw new Exception("Chore required");
        }
        $id = $chore->getId();
        if ($id == null) {
            throw new Exception("Chore id required");
        }
        $sql = "DELETE FROM Chore WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($chore->getId());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not delete Chore: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
    }

    public function update($chore) {
        if (!isset($chore)) {
            throw new Exception("Chore required");
        }
        $id = $chore->getId();
        if ($id == null) {
            throw new Exception("Chore id required");
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE Chore SET chore_name = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($chore->getChoreName());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not update Chore: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
    }

    public function getChore($id) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Chore WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($id);
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve Chore: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $chore = null;
        if ($stmt->rowCount == 1) {
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            $id = $row['id'];
            $chore_name = $row['house_name'];

            $chore = new ChoreDAO($id, $chore_name);
        }
        return $chore;
    }

    public function getChores() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM  Chore";
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute();
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve chores: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $chores = array();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        while ($row != null) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $chore_name = $row['chore_name'];

            $chore= new ChoreDAO($i, $chore_name);
            $chores[$id] = $chore;

            $row = $stmt->fetch();
        }
        return $chores;
    }
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: which is the undefined method?

Comment: sorry, in the view_chores.php
this line of code :
 echo "<b>Title:</b> " . $chore->getChoreName() . "<br />";

Comment: Create a 5-10 line testcase please. You need to do more debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ChoreDAO class getChores() method, you are using this:

```
$chore= new ChoreDAO($i, $chore_name);
```

Where it should be:

```
$chore= new Chore($i, $chore_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

getChoreName() exists in Chore.
So, Chore::getChoreName() exists but you aren't using that class. Perhaps you meant for ChoreDAO to extend the Chore class?

Comment: He's calling it on a `Chore`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what scrollbars have to do with anything, but ok.

Answer (score 0):

Also, look at shouldn't Chore::setChoreName()

Shouldn't `$this->ChoreName` be `$this->chore_name`?